# Why can't I redirect to Index?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I cannot return anywhere after setting cookie, the cookie sets properly but **after setting the cookie**, **it wont redirect anywhere**.

Here is my code in view:

```
<a onclick="changeGuestCity(@city.LocationId)">
   <span class="font-400 opacity-70">@city.LocationTitle</span>
</a>
```

Here is the JavaScript's function:

```
<script>

        function changeGuestCity(id) {
            $.get("/Home/ChangeGuestCity/" + id);
        }

</script>
```

Here is my the function but doesn't redirect to Index or anywhere else:

```
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }



 public IActionResult ChangeGuestCity(int? id)
 {

     if (id == null)
         return Redirect("/");

     CookieOptions cityCookie = new CookieOptions()
     {
         Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
     };

     Response.Cookies.Append("city", id.ToString(), cityCookie);

     return Redirect("/");
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: A redirect in an ajax request only redirects the response to that request. Not sure why you are using ajax at all here based on the flow you seem to want. Can do what you want with `location.href = "/Home/ChangeGuestCity/" + id`

Comment: @Crowcoder The JS code works fine, it sends the LocationId to my controller's method (ChangeGuestCity) and the ChangeGuestCity's method does set the cookie as well. but the return doesn't work !

Comment: Shouldn't you either set the id as a query param, or specify in the ChangeGuestCity implementation that id is a url segment?
e.g `/Home/ChangeGuestCity/?id="+id` 
or
`[Route("/Home/ChangeGuestCity/{id}")]`

Comment: The action will properly return a redirect but your AJAX call in JavaScript will not respect that result. You will have to redirect the client manually using JavaScript if you want to call your endpoint through JavaScript.

Comment: @poke would you please give me the exact code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to redirect to some where when you click the  tag?

You can't redirect from $.get(), here are two ways:

You can set the page you want to direct to in href:

`<a href="controller/action" onclick="changeGuestCity(@city.LocationId)">`

Or redirect in your javascript:

```
function changeGuestCity(id) {
        $.get("/Home/ChangeGuestCity/" + id);
        window.location.href = "controller/action";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
return Index();
```